# Count duplicated column data

Tags: sql

I have the data like that:

```
UserId   LocationId   ProjectId
  1         123          1234
  1         323          1234
  2         213          1234
  3         234          1234
  1         123          2345
  1         323          2345
  2         213          2345
  3         234          2345
```

I need to show data of UserIds that are duplicated in a ProjectId using column `Count`

```
    UserId   LocationId   ProjectId  Count
      1         123          1234      2
      1         323          1234      2
      2         213          1234      1
      3         234          1234      1
      1         123          2345      2
      1         323          2345      2
      2         213          2345      1
      3         234          2345      1
```

Will be glad for any help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 Select UserId   
        LocationId  
        ProjectId,
       (Select Count(*) From TableName t2 Where t2.UserId = t1.UserID And t2.ProjectId = t1.ProjectId) As Count
 From TableName t1
```

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you would solve this most succinctly and efficiently using ANSI standard window functions:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by projectid, userid) as usercount
from table t;
```

Comment: I have tried your version and for me it doesn't work

Comment: @SolomiiaKalinchuk . . . You don't mention the database in your question, and this is ANSI standard functionality supported by most (but not all) databases.